# Is there a way to get a list of answers with a specific tag that a given user has answered on SO?

Tags: support, search

I know how to get all answers tagged with X. I know how to find a given user's answers. Is there a way to do a cross between the two?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way that involves the least to remember and type is:

- Go to their profile page.
- Click on the tag there.

[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:1711796+[algorithm]

(you can also click on "view more" for a list of all tags and click on any tag there)

---

Alternatively, when on their profile page, their user ID is already populated in the search box at the top right of the screen:

[image]

From here you can just add `[tagName]` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

For either of the above, you'll need to add `is:answer` if you're only looking for answers.

Comment: This also returns questions. Would need `is:answer` to fully meet the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Just search for questions / answers using the search box (or the given URL) and pass in the user identifier, for instance:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1021725+xacml
```

- user%3A1021725 represents the user
- ... (here +xacml) is a search term.

Comment: That's clear as mud. `user:123456 [xaml]` (or `user:me`) in the search bar is a but more readable.